# ORA-01407: cannot update to NULL Trying to get actual number

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-null

I have a trigger that statement that compares to date values and subtracts them. Depending on which number is greater it will multiply different numbers. This should store an actual value but currently it is trying to store a null value, which I do not want.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BALANCE_FEE
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON CHARTERS
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
FEE NUMBER;
ACL_DATE DATE;
EXP_DATE DATE;
GRP_ID VARCHAR2(20);

BEGIN

ACL_DATE := :NEW.ACL_RETURN_DATE;
EXP_DATE := :NEW.EXP_RETURN_DATE;
GRP_ID := :NEW.GRP_ID;


IF ACL_DATE > EXP_DATE
THEN
FEE := ((ACL_DATE - EXP_DATE) * 75);

IF ACL_DATE < EXP_DATE
THEN
FEE := ((ACL_DATE - EXP_DATE)* -20);

END IF;
END IF;
UPDATE CUSTOMER
     SET CUSTOMER.BALANCE = CUSTOMER.BALANCE + FEE
     WHERE CUSTOMER.GRP_ID = GRP_ID;
END;
/
SHOW ERROR;
```

Tables used in Trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
    CUS_FNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CUS_LNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    GENDER VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PHONENUM NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    CITY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PARTY_COUNT INT NOT NULL,
    GRP_ID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CAN_RENT VARCHAR(20),
    BALANCE NUMBER NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE CHARTERS (
    CHARTER_ID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    BOAT_ID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES BOAT(BOAT_ID),
    GRP_ID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES CUSTOMER(GRP_ID),
    EXP_RETURN_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    ACL_RETURN_DATE DATE NOT NULL);
```

I am getting this error

```
INSERT INTO CHARTERS (CHARTER_ID,BOAT_ID,EXP_RETURN_DATE,ACL_RETURN_DATE,GRP_ID) VALUES ('T002','B002',TO_DATE ('2019/03/10', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),TO_DATE ('2019/03/08', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),'G001')
Error report -
ORA-01407: cannot update ("ADMIN_BF"."CUSTOMER"."BALANCE") to NULL
ORA-06512: at "ADMIN_BF.BALANCE_FEE", line 24
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ADMIN_BF.BALANCE_FEE'
```

When running these insert statements I get the error

```
INSERT INTO CHARTERS (CHARTER_ID,BOAT_ID,EXP_RETURN_DATE,ACL_RETURN_DATE,GRP_ID) VALUES ('T002','B002',TO_DATE ('2019/03/10', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),TO_DATE ('2019/03/08', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),'G001');

INSERT INTO CHARTERS (CHARTER_ID,BOAT_ID,EXP_RETURN_DATE,ACL_RETURN_DATE,GRP_ID) VALUES ('T001','B001',TO_DATE ('2019/01/20', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),TO_DATE ('2019/01/20', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),'G002');
```

When I run this statement I get no error

```
INSERT INTO CHARTERS (CHARTER_ID,BOAT_ID,EXP_RETURN_DATE,ACL_RETURN_DATE,GRP_ID) VALUES ('T003','B003',TO_DATE ('2019/05/05', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),TO_DATE ('2019/05/07', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),'G003');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `trigger`, You are missing the equal condition.

You have `IF ACL_DATE > EXP_DATE` and `IF ACL_DATE < EXP_DATE` in your trigger code but `Fee` will be null if `ACL_DATE = EXP_DATE` as it will not satisfy any `IF` condition.

so `FEE` will be null as you have not even initialized it and

```
CUSTOMER.BALANCE + FEE(which is null) --> results in null
```

and `CUSTOMER.BALANCE` has not null constraint which is violating.

The best solution is to initialize the `FEE` variable with some initial value (0).

```
...
...
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
FEE NUMBER := 0; -- this
ACL_DATE DATE;
EXP_DATE DATE;
...
...
```

Comment: This worked but not I have another problem. When I run this trigger it updates my whole table where I want it to only update each individual customer.grp_id

Comment: Your variable in trigger and column in table has same name. query will consider `WHERE CUSTOMER.GRP_ID = GRP_ID` as always true. use different variable name or directly use :NEW here as `WHERE CUSTOMER.GRP_ID = :NEW.GRP_ID;`

Comment: You are a lifesaver and I appreciate all the help @Popeye

Answer (score 1):

You've nested your second if so that it will only be evaluated if the first evaluates to `true`:

```
IF ACL_DATE > EXP_DATE
THEN
FEE := ((ACL_DATE - EXP_DATE) * 75);

IF ACL_DATE < EXP_DATE
THEN
FEE := ((ACL_DATE - EXP_DATE)* -20);

END IF;
END IF;
```

You might have wanted an `ELSIF`:

```
IF ACL_DATE > EXP_DATE
THEN
FEE := ((ACL_DATE - EXP_DATE) * 75);

ELSIF ACL_DATE < EXP_DATE
THEN
FEE := ((ACL_DATE - EXP_DATE)* -20);

END IF;
```

But if you also need to account for if the two dates are equal:

```
IF ACL_DATE > EXP_DATE
THEN
FEE := ((ACL_DATE - EXP_DATE) * 75);

ELSIF ACL_DATE < EXP_DATE
THEN
FEE := ((ACL_DATE - EXP_DATE)* -20);
else
fee := 0; --maybe

END IF;
```

Comment: This helped me understand how to use Ifs and ELSIFS thanks!